# Java program runs fine in Eclipse but not as a .jar file (Is the config path wrong??)

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, jar

I've got an issue with my .jar file. It runs fine in Eclipse but as soon as I export it, it won't open. I've checked the manifest file and it looks like it's okay.
Im using the ssh classes from [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).
Can anyone check the code and tell me, what's wrong, please?

Here's my code:
Class SSHServerRestart:

```
package SSHServerRestartPackage;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SSHServerRestart
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        Config config = new Config();

        try
        {
            URL location = SSHServerRestart.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
            config = InitConfiguration(location.getPath() + "Config.xml");
            System.out.println("Konfiguration geladen.");

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(config.getUser(), config.getServerName(), config.getServerPort());
            session.setPassword(config.getPassword());
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(props);
            session.connect();
            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            System.out.println("Server wird neu gestartet");
            channel.setCommand("reboot");
            channel.connect();
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Beliebige Taste drücken, um das Programm zu beenden");
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Beliebige Taste drücken, um das Programm zu beenden");
            System.in.read();
        }
    }

    private static Config InitConfiguration(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        Config configTemp = new Config();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            XMLDecoder xmlDecoder = new XMLDecoder(bis);
            configTemp = (Config) xmlDecoder.readObject();
            xmlDecoder.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Beliebige Taste drücken, um das Programm zu beenden");
            System.in.read();
        }
        return configTemp;
    }
}
```

Class Config:

```
package SSHServerRestartPackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Config implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String serverName;
    private int serverPort;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    public String getServerName() 
    {
        return serverName;
    }
    public void setServerName(String serverName) 
    {
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }
    public int getServerPort() 
    {
        return serverPort;
    }
    public void setServerPort(int serverPort) 
    {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }
    public String getUser() 
    {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) 
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getPassword() 
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) 
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And the Config.xml-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<java version="1.8.0_20" class="SSHServerRestartPackage.SSHServerRestart">
    <object class="SSHServerRestartPackage.Config">
        <void property="serverName">
            <string>202.202.202.202</string>
        </void>
        <void property="serverPort">
            <int>22</int>
        </void>
        <void property="user">
            <string>root</string>
        </void>
        <void property="password">
            <string>IhrPasswort</string>
        </void>
    </object>
</java>
```

Comment: You probably should mention in which way it is not working. Command line arguments, class path, errors, stacktraces...

Comment: I think there's a problem with file `Config.xml`. Try to debug the program in order to find out whether the file is loaded properly. I've experienced a lot of trouble with file loading from `.jar`.

Comment: @petrbel: You're right. It says that the Config.xml is not found...

Comment: @FranzHuber23 please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with loading the XML file from the `.jar`. You may use the following command instead:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/to/my/file");
```

But be aware, the `input` variable isn't a `File` nor `String` but [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). However, you may read the whole content of the stream into string and parse it later (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/1364327))

In order to understand the problem, one must realize that `.jar` is simply an archive (i.e. a single file, not a directory). Java implicitly can't address some "subfiles" of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for it:

```
InputStream input = SSHServerRestart.class.getResourceAsStream("/SSHServerRestartPackage/Config.xml");
        config = InitConfiguration(input);
```

And the method InitConfiguration:

```
private static Config InitConfiguration(InputStream bis) throws IOException
    {
        Config configTemp = new Config();
        try
        {
            XMLDecoder xmlDecoder = new XMLDecoder(bis);
            configTemp = (Config) xmlDecoder.readObject();
            xmlDecoder.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Beliebige Taste drücken, um das Programm zu beenden");
            System.in.read();
        }
        return configTemp;
    }
```

Comment: Whole solution: http://franzhuber23.blogspot.de/2015/11/java-ssh-mit-configxml.html